# Powershell to Print Duplex Paper of PDF File

Tags: printing, duplex, powershell-7

(Sorry for my grammar because I used a translator.)
I have tried many solutions searched from this forum as well as from Google to write a PowerShell code for duplex printing of PDF files.
Thank you!

I tried to execute the command "Start-Process -FilePath document.pdf -Verb Print" or using the method "New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument", but both cannot print double-sided (Duplex) pages. My printer is a Canon LBP226dw and supports duplex printing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/set-printconfiguration?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: I used the command code according to this link to set up -DuplexingMode = TwoSidedShortEdge and then print but still can’t print double-sided.